# How to obtain unique set of rows in nested data frame?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, type-conversion, tidyverse

I am trying to extract unique sets of rows in nested data frame.

Initial data frame is shown below:

```
df <- data.frame(
    hid=c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
    mid=c(1,2,3,4,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4),
    tmid=c("010","01010","010","01020",
           "010","0120","010","010","020",
           "010","01010","010","01020"),
    thid=c("010","02020","010","02020",
           "000","0120","010","010","010",
           "010","02020","010","02020"),
    tdid=c("000","01010","010","02020",
           "000","0100","010","010","010",
           "000","01010","010","02020"),
    tiid=c("010","02020","010","01020",
           "020","0220","020","020","020",
           "010","02020","010","01020")
    )
```

Printed in dara frame:

```
> df
   hid mid  tmid  thid  tdid  tiid
1    1   1   010   010   000   010
2    1   2 01010 02020 01010 02020
3    1   3   010   010   010   010
4    1   4 01020 02020 02020 01020
5    2   1   010   000   000   020
6    2   2  0120  0120  0100  0220
7    2   3   010   010   010   020
8    2   4   010   010   010   020
9    2   5   020   010   010   020
10   3   1   010   010   000   010
11   3   2 01010 02020 01010 02020
12   3   3   010   010   010   010
13   3   4 01020 02020 02020 01020
```

This data frame is composed of following fields:

- `hid`: household id
- `mid`: household member id
- `tmid, thid, tdid, tiid`: variables indicating chain of activity of each household member by different definition, such as 0(stay in home)-1(activity outside home)-0(staying home)

Now, I need to extract unique set of member activities taken by households. I am not only extracting unique rows in each households but also need to extract the sets itselves. Thus `df %>% distinct(hid,tmid,tdid,tiid)` won't work to extract distinct set of activities and `df %>% distinct(hid,tmid,tdid,tiid)` cannot take set of activities in each household into account. Desired output is shown below:

```
> df.unique
   shid smid tmid  thid  tdid  tiid
1   1    1   010   010   000   010
2   1    2   010   010   010   010
3   1    3 01010 02020 01010 02020
4   1    4 01020 02020 02020 01020
5   2    1   010   000   000   020
6   2    2   010   010   010   020
7   2    3   020   010   010   020
8   2    4  0120  0120  0100  0220
```

The difference between previous data frame are:

- Duplicated rows in `hid==2` are removed (**removing duplicated rows in each household**)
- `hid==3` is removed (**removing household which has completely the same set of activities compared with other households**)
- `hid` and `mid` are replaced by sequential number (unique id of household and member do not have any meaning)

The first and third points could be solved, however, the second point could not be done currenlty as it is not possible to implement it simply by applying `distinct()`.

I assume that it may be possible to convert it into nested data frame and compare nested data frame inside.
Currently I prepared following nested data frame.

```
> df.nest <- df.unique %>% dplyr::select(-n) %>% group_by(hid) %>% nest()
> df.nest$data
[[1]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   smid   tmid   thid   tdid   tiid
  <int> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1     1    010    010    000    010
2     2    010    010    010    010
3     3  01010  02020  01010  02020
4     4  01020  02020  02020  01020

[[2]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   smid   tmid   thid   tdid   tiid
  <int> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1     1    010    000    000    020
2     2    010    010    010    020
3     3   0120   0120   0100   0220
4     4    020    010    010    020

[[3]]
# A tibble: 4 x 5
   smid   tmid   thid   tdid   tiid
  <int> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <fctr>
1     1    010    010    000    010
2     2    010    010    010    010
3     3  01010  02020  01010  02020
4     4  01020  02020  02020  01020
```

*`sid` is newly added to replace `mid` by sequential number as member id isn't important anymore

Any idea to remove `[[3]]`, which has the same data frames in `[[1]]`, from the nested list (or general data frame format previously shown as `df.unique`)?

As actual dara frame contains over 60,000 households, I need the way to implement it not manually such as `df.nest[1:2,]`. Other solution which does not use nested data frame is also appreciated.

I found functions named `all_equal/all.equal` and `identical`, however those are used to compare two data frames.

Comment: Why is the row of `hid==2 && mid==5` removed?

Comment: @useR  Thank you for the comment. It is not removed but represented by `shid==2  && smid==3` as it was arranged by `count()`. `df.unique` was created by `df.unique <- df %>% count(hid,tmid,thid,tdid,tiid) %>% group_by(hid) %>% mutate(smid=row_number()) %>% dplyr::select(hid,smid,tmid,thid,tdid,tiid,n)` (`hid` is not renamed by `shid` in this script)

Comment: So are you removing both duplicated groups, as well as duplicated rows _within_ groups?

Comment: @uerR Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score -2):

The function !duplicated can delete the duplicated rows.
Example:
df [!duplicated(df[c("hid","mid", "tmid" , "thid",  "tdid" , "tiid")]),]

Comment: Thanks but it might not work as `hid` differentiate each household which have completely the same records. If `hid` is removed from the script, it cannot recognize pairs of records in each household. This is the issue that I am tackling with.